# SendGrid: no IPs are available for this account

Tags: email, twilio, sendgrid

While sending emails via SendGrid it shows the status as processed and the following error:

[image: SendGrid error]

What could the issue be?

Answer (score 4):

Went through the same thing, this error indicates that your account has no dedicated IP. this can be caused by a suspended/deactivated/downgraded account, or in my case, after a billing issue was resolved no IP was added automatically. best solution is to contact the Sendgrid support and ask for help, or try to set up a new one in settings -> IP Addresses

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here,

Was caused by an account lock for no reasons by the Sendgrid teams, the quickest customer service was to directly use their chat as their team answering on customer support tickets isn't really expert and takes hours to answer: https://support.sendgrid.com/hc/en-us/requests/new

If you are using sendgrid and seek instant support, i highly recommend you to change of service

[image]